Ansible: build shell command depending on variables set
Let's say I would like to run the following task from ansible:
    - name: dns-cloudflare | Request certificate
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: certbot certonly \
              --dns-cloudflare \
              --dns-cloudflare-credentials {{ certbot_cloudflare_credentials_file }} \
              --non-interactive \
              --agree-tos \
              --expand \
              --email {{ certbot_email }} \
              --domain {{ __domains }}
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        creates: "{{ certbot_directory }}/{{ item.name }}/{{ item.name }}/cert.pem"

I build it with a block like this:
certbot_cert:
  - name: test1.example.com
    cn:
      - test2-cn.example.com
    post-hook: systemctl restart apache2
  - name: test3.example.com

I want to add the --post-hook argument to my certbot command depending on whether item.post-hook. And the content for this hook is not static, whatever I type in there should land in my certbot command like --post-hook 'systemctl restart apache2'
But when I don't define this variable, there should not be an empty post-hook, it should not be in the certbot command at all.
How can I achieve this?
I played around with variables and filters and I read through the documentation but I didn't find a proper way to handle is. Duplication this task several times for every possible optional argument should not be the way.

Since you can have blank lines in a shell command as long as you escape the line feed, you could have a line:  {{ "--post-hook '" ~ item['post-hook'] ~ "'" if item['post-hook'] is defined }} \. This said, I would be surprised if there was not an existing module which would provide you the cerbot integration, where you could probably do an easier post_hook: "{{ item['post-hook'] | default(omit) }}".

^-- https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-certbot

The way you've written the value of cmd does not preserve newlines -- which is what you want, since that means (a) you don't need to escape (\) the end of lines like you've done in your example, and (b) you can conveniently use jinja conditionals to suppress some lines.
Like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    certbot_cloudflare_credentials_file: creds.conf
    certbot_email: alice@example.com
    __domains: example.com
    certbot_directory: certs
    certbot_cert:
    - name: test1.example.com
      cn:
        - test2-cn.example.com
      post-hook: systemctl restart apache2
    - name: test3.example.com
  tasks:
    - name: dns-cloudflare | Request certificate
      loop: "{{ certbot_cert }}"
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: certbot certonly
          --dns-cloudflare
          --dns-cloudflare-credentials "{{ certbot_cloudflare_credentials_file }}"
          --non-interactive
          --agree-tos
          --expand
          --email "{{ certbot_email }}"
          --domain "{{ __domains }}"
          {% if 'post-hook' in item %}
          --post-hook "{{ item["post-hook"] }}"
          {% endif %}
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        creates: "{{ certbot_directory }}/{{ item.name }}/{{ item.name }}/cert.pem"

For the first item in certbot_cert, this will run:
certbot certonly --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials creds.conf --non-interactive --agree-tos --expand --email alice@example.com --domain example.com --post-hook systemctl restart apache2

And for the second line it will run:
certbot certonly --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials creds.conf --non-interactive --agree-tos --expand --email alice@example.com --domain example.com


I had finally the time to test the whole role, but when I use this I get the following error `  msg: |-
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'post'
The error appears to be in '/opt/pscloud/ansible/roles/certbot/tasks/dns-cloudflare-without-cn.yaml': line 8, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: dns-cloudflare | Request certificate
      ^ here`

Is a dash allowed in an variable name?

A dash is not allowed in a variable name, but it's perfectly valid in a dictionary key. The playbook shown here runs as written without any errors on my system, which has python 3.12.3 and Ansible 2.16.7.
